# Django: OperationalError with No such column

Tags: python, django

I'm very new to databases (to the extent that I know nothing about them) and Django, although I know Python well. I'm using Sqlite as my database software. I keep getting a

```
OperationalError at /admin/auth/user/add/ 
table dashboard_member has no column named user_id
```

error every time I try to add a new user from the Django Admin Panel. Here is my models.py:

```
from django.db import models    # importing database library from Django   
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Member(models.Model):    # table for members' info

    DEPARTMENTS = (
        ('Quiz', 'Quizzing'),
        ('Design', 'Design'),
        ('Elec', 'Electronics'),
        ('Prog', 'Programming'),
    )

    CLASSES = (                 # tuples to store choices for each field
        (9, '9'),               # (actual value to be stored, human-readable value),
        (10, '10'),
        (11, '11'),
        (12, '12'),
    )

    DESIGNATIONS = (
        ('Mem', 'Member'),      
        ('ExecMem', 'Executive Member'),
        ('VicePres', 'Vice President'),
        ('Pres', 'President'),
    )

    user = models.OneToOneField(User)   # to inherit the properties of the base User class in Django, like first_name, last_name, password, username, etc.
    schoolClass = models.IntegerField('Class', choices = CLASSES)
    desig = models.CharField('Designation', max_length = 20, choices = DESIGNATIONS)
    dept1 = models.CharField('Department 1', max_length = 20, choices = DEPARTMENTS)
    dept2 = models.CharField('Department 2', max_length = 20, choices = DEPARTMENTS)
    #proPic = models.ImageField('Profile Picture', upload_to = 'profile_pics')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username

class DepInfo(models.Model):        # table for info specific to each department

    DEPARTMENTS = (
        ('Quiz', 'Quizzing'),
        ('Design', 'Design'),
        ('Elec', 'Electronics'),
        ('Prog', 'Programming'),
    )

    dept = models.CharField('Department', max_length = 20, choices = DEPARTMENTS)
    agenda = models.TextField('Agenda', max_length = 1000)      # editable text fields
    workMat = models.TextField('Working Material', max_length = 1000)
    furRead = models.TextField('Further Reading', max_length = 1000)
```

And here is my admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import User

from dashboard.models import Member, DepInfo

class MemberInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Member
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'member'

class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = (MemberInline, )

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
#admin.site.register(Member)
admin.site.register(DepInfo)

# Register your models here.
```

Thing is, I haven't even defined any column user_id and when I create the tables, it doesn't show any column called user_id. Could someone please help me rectify this?

Comment: your table doesnot have that column. General Advice: use south to migrate your db so that new columns will be added everytime when you add new column to your db.

Comment: I am having a similar problem. i am doing makemigration and it asks me two options which i dont get. I get the following message. How do i proceed further ?

You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'user' 
we can't do that (the database needs something to 
Please select a fix: 
1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on 
2) Quit, and let me add a default in models. py 
Select an option: 
to post without a default; 
populate existing rows) . 
all existing rows)

Answer (score 0):

Manually delete migrations files available as .py in myapp/migrations. The files are of form: **init**.0001.py, 0002_migrations.py.
Delete all such types and perform:

> $:   python manage.py makemigrations myapp
>
> $:   python manage.py migrate myapp 0001
>
> $:   python manage.py sqlmigrate myapp 0001